# Does 'Homeomorphism' describe Kuratowski's theorem accurately?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, planar-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph.

- The **edge subdivision operation** for an edge $\{u, v\} \in E$ is the deletion of $\{u, v\}$ from $G$ and the addition of two edges $\{u, w\}$ and $\{w, v\}$ along with the new vertex $w$.
- A graph which has been derived from $G$ by a sequence of edge subdivision operations is called a **subdivision** of $G$.
- Two graphs $G$ and  $G'$ are **homeomorphic** if there is a graph isomorphism from *some subdivision* of  $G$ to *some subdivision* of  $G'$.

The following example illustrates that $G$ is not a subdivision of $H$, and $H$ is also not a subdivision of $G$, but $G$ and $H$ are homeomorphic since $G'$  is isomorphic to $H'$ where $G'$ and $H'$ are some subdivisions of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

[image: ![enter image description here]

A well known **Kuratowski's Theorem** stated that  a graph $G$ is planar if and only if $G$ does not contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of  $K_{5}$  or of $K_{3,3}$.

[Homeomorphism (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Embedding_on_a_surface) (Wiki) describes Kuratowski's Theorem with the terminology *homeomorphism*. It said:

> Kuratowski's theorem states that: A finite graph is planar if and only
> if it contains **no subgraph homeomorphic to** $K_5$ (complete graph on
> five vertices) or $K_{3,3}$ (complete bipartite graph on six vertices,
> three of which connect to each of the other three).

But by the definition of graph homeomorphic, it seems to assert that, in Kuratowski's theorem, a graph $G$ is planar if and only if it does not contain **a subgraph whose subdivision** ($\color{red}{not~ refer~ subgraph!}$) is isomorphic to **a subdivision of $K_5$  or $K_{3,3}$.**

So I'm quite puzzled. I feel that the use of the term "homeomorphism"  might not align with Kuratowski's original intent.   There are some subtle distinctions, and I believe they are not equivalent from a literal standpoint.

**I would like to ask, what does 'subgraph homeomorphic to' mean here?**

If it refers to a subgraph of $G$ is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ and $K_5$, it is OK.  However, if it says that **some subdivision of a subgraph** of $G$ is some subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$, then I am confused.

Comment: What exact;y are you confused about?

Comment: I think if we use homeomorphic , then  it refers to some subdivision of a subgraph  isomorphic to some subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.  However, the Kuratowski theorem states that a **subgraph** is isomorphic to a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: The homeomorphic relation of finite graphs is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Right? Or are you confused by something else?

Comment: @kabenyuk  Kuratowski's Theorem determines the planarity of a graph through the subgraphs of $G$. It checks whether there is a subgraph isomorphic to some  subdivision of  $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. However, using homeomorphism does not involve directly finding subgraphs of the graph, but rather subdivision of subgraphs. (which  is  a subdivision  of  $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$) I would like to ask, what does 'subgraph homeomorphic to' mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more direct way to state Kuratowski's condition for non-planar graphs is "$G$ has a subgraph $H$ which is isomorphic to a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$". If we were to say "$G$ has a subgraph $H$ which is homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$", we'd be saying "$G$ has a subgraph $H$ which has a subdivision isomorphic to a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$": this needlessly subdivides the subgraph of $G$.

Nevertheless, the two forms of the condition are equivalent. If $H$ has a subdivision $H'$ isomorphic to a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$, then $H$ itself is isomorphic to a (different) subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$. In fact, the same thing is true if we replace $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ by any graph with minimum degree at least $3$.

The idea is that $H$, $H'$, and every intermediate subdivision maintain a correspondence between their degree-$3$-or-more vertices, which are never changed; the only thing that varies is the length of the paths between them. (These paths are just edges in the case of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.) So $H$ must already have the right number of degree-$3$-or-more vertices, with the right pairs of them connected by internally disjoint paths, which means it already has the structure of the subdivision we want.

Comment: Thank you!. Indeed, having a minimum degree of three or greater is a crucial condition. Note that  some articles (like Takao Asano,  *An approach to the subgraph homeomorphism problem*)  describe it like this: The subgraph homeomorphism problem for a fixed pattern graph $H$ is stated as 
follows: given an input graph $G = ( V, E)$, determine whether $G$ has a subgraph 
homeomorphic to $H$, i.e., a subgraph isomorphic to a graph obtained from $H$ by a 
sequence of subdivisions of edges.